# GetUser is not being read

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So I am working on a kick command on my discord bot in javascript with discord.js v14. However, I am getting this error

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getUser')
```

I tried googling some code examples but they are also using similar code and not having an error. What am I missing?

Here is my kick command:

const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("discord.js");

```
module.exports={
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("kick")
    .setDescription("Kick the member provided")
    //.setDefaultMemberPermissions(PermissionFlagsBits.KickMembers)
    .addUserOption(option=>
        option.setName("target")
        .setDescription("The member you'd like to kick'")
        .setRequired(true))
    .addStringOption(option=>option.setName('reason')
    .setDescription("The reason for kicking the member provided")),
    async execute(interaction,client){
        console.log(interaction.options); // Check if options is defined
        const user=interaction.options.getUser("target");
        console.log(user);
        //const user=interaction.options.getUser('target');
        let reason=interaction.options.getString('reason');
        const member = await interaction.guild.members
            .fetch(user.id)
            .catch(console.error);
        if (!reason) reason="Skill issue.";
        await member.kick(reason).catch(console.error);
    user.send({content: `You have been kicked from ${interaction.guild.name}\nReason :${reason}`})
    .catch(console.log('user\'s DM\'s are off.'));
    },
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Update: I realized that    async execute(interaction,client) is not working because of how I formatted the code

Comment: Code **formatting** doesn't change code execution--you may have meant that your code was **incorrect** in that the `execute` method was in the wrong place. Consistent, logical indentation goes a long way to avoiding errors like this.